# Unknown character after migrating database like "Famous Paintings�Birds"

Tags: php, mysql, frontend, mariadb

[image: Unknown character after migrating database]
Did you see that?
**Unknown character after migrating database!**
I've moved a website from one Server to another one. After moving the site, it's working fine except this thing. The unknown characters, generally aposthophie, space. It's showing fine in phpmyadmin, but showing as unknown in the frontend. Any solutions?
The database and table collection is set to "utf8_general_ci".
Converting it to "utf8mb4_general_ci" didn't solve the issue.
So i converted back again. The problem remains.

The charecters:

- Famous Paintings�Birds
- Flocks�Birds Around Us
- Water�Birds Live Around Us
- Turkey�Birds You Should Know
- Most Common Songs�Birds That Live Around You

The database and table collection is set to "utf8_general_ci".
Converting it to "utf8mb4_general_ci" didn't solve the issue.
So i converted back again. The problem remains.

I'm expecting the charecters will appear as normal in the frontend!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through